# Illegal token in meteor/node module => cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, meteor, meteorite

I was attempting to follow along with g00glen00b's meteor/twitter walkthrough (http://g00glen00b.be/meteor-twitter-streaming/) when i got this persistent error. any help or hints would be much obliged.

## things i tried

- uninstall/reinstall npm
- uninstall/reinstall twitter package
- uninstall/reinstall cookies
- searching for hidden characters

## my deployed app

(htp://dbcmarch.meteor.com)

## meteor error

```
 => Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
node_modules/twitter/node_modules/cookies/test/express.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/twitter/node_modules/cookies/test/http.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

## express.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var assert = require("assert"),
    express = require("express"),
```

## http.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var assert = require("assert"),
    http = require("http"),
```

Comment: The shebang expression is the issue, it's not valid syntax. To execute it you'd give your script `chmod +x`, then you can run it like `./file.js`, but you don't need it, I think you're misusing it.

Comment: @elclanrs I ran which node and it points to => /usr/bin/node, so im not sure if thats the problem. i also ran chmod +X on the test dir to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meteor includes npm, and its perfectly acceptable to run 'mrt add npm' however npm should not be used to install its packages (e.g. npm install twitter) into a meteor project. you can require them via a packages.json file.

in order to avoid the illegal token error and get the server up running, i deleted the primary node_module dir in my project folder.

check the meteor google group for advice!